# Cocoa-Touch – pushViewController when using ARC

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, automatic-ref-counting

I'm wondering how I would write my `- tabliView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method when using ARC.

With ARC I do this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (self.addContactsVC == nil) {
        self.addContactsVC = [[AddContactsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    }

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.addContactsVC animated:YES];

}
```

What I'm wondering is that is it too much overhead that I'm saving the view controller as a class variable. I'm think if it's "good practice" that I can reuse the view controller each time I want to push it onto the stack instead of allocating a new one every time I want to push the view controller?

Maybe I should just do instead?:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    AddContactsViewController *addContactsVC = [[AddContactsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:addContactsVC animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a classic tradeoff between time and space.

- If you instantiate the VC and save it, then you will present that VC controller to user faster the second time around.  However you then carry the memory allocation of that view controller even though it is not being used.
- On the other hand, if you  allocate the VC only when it is needed, then you save on memory in the long run (depending on when ARC disposes the previous VC), but you lose the speed gain over pre-allocating the class.

Without further information, the answer to your question is "It depends... ".  And that will depend on where/if you are seeing bottlenecks in your application when you thoroughly profile memory usage and speed performance.

Personally I'd prefer to allocate the VC when you need it as that simplifies the code all over.  Only if and when users complain about the App appearing slow would I consider caching the VC.

Comment: Another reason for saving the view controller is if you want to be able to keep the current state of the view controller when popping and pushing it.

Comment: @PeterWarbo .. at first I thought "hmm .. hadn't thought of that", then I thought "Hmm the state should be in the model".  Not sure if either of those thoughts are definitive.

Comment: Well, the model objects like `NSString` are set in the view controller that gets pushed and popped. If I allocate the view controller every time to push it then the model objects will be nil unless I reuse the same view controller.